# Monaca 6.2になってWindowsのビルドができない

Tags: monaca, windows

初めての質問です。
よろしくおねがいします。
MonacaでWindowsのアプリを作っていますが
5.2は問題なくビルドできます。
6.2にすると準備中から前にすすまずビルドできません。
どなたか、何か参考になる情報をご提供ください。
よろしくおねがいします。

---

**コメントより**
6.2はサンプルの`Onsen UI V1 Sliding Menu`と、`Onsen UI V1 Windows Universal`に
`jQuely`,`WinJs`を追加しています。 5.2は同じ構成のものです
Frameworkのバージョンが5.2から6.2に変更になってから発生しています。
6.2はAndroidのデバッグモードでのビルドは出来ています。

6.2でのビルドの対応ははもう少し先になるという情報をいただきました。
皆様、ご対応ありがございました。

そろそろ対応してあるかとやってみましたが
まだでした。
ただし
Cordova6系のビルドは、近日リリース予定です
と表示されわかりやすくなっていました。

Comment: `Monaca`が5.2なのではなく`Cordova Framework`のバージョンが5.2なのでは？、また、プロジェクトの内容について触れていないので、色々なケースが想定されます。このままでは回答がつかないかもしれないです。せめて新規で作成したプロジェクトがビルドできないのか、以前から使用していたプロジェクトをアップデートしたのか、新規に作成したプロジェクトはビルドできるのか？など思いつく限り詳細に状況を記載してください。

Comment: Myaku様ご指摘ありがとうございます。Frameworkのバージョンが5.2から6.2に変更になってから発生しています。

Comment: 追加情報は本文を修正する形で行い、コメントした方に伝えたい場合は「追記した旨」を伝えるといいです。(追記情報が見づらいのと、コメント文が長くなってしまうので)

Comment: 色々ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: WindowsはCordova 6.2ではビルド出来ません。ビルド出来るのはiOS/Androidのみです。Windowsも近いうちにビルド出来るようになる予定です。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: KNaito様　貴重な情報ありがとうございます。しばらくのあいだ５．２で開発します。

Comment: Monacaの開発チームメンバーの方（https://monaca.io/about-us.html#monacateamList）かとは思いますが、回答はコメントで行わないでください。また、質問者の方は解決した場合に回答がない場合は自己回答を行い、その回答を後日承認してください。

Comment: @Myakuさん、分かりました。

Answer (score 1):

**コメントより**
WindowsはCordova 6.2ではビルド出来ません。
ビルド出来るのはiOS/Androidのみです。
Windowsも近いうちにビルド出来るように‌​なる予定です。
すみませんが、よろしくお願‌​いします。